# Export Facebook Friends Email Address Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am on a project that involve facebook integration.
Following the  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile i am able to integrate the sdk into my application and it runs pretty smooth as well.

Its like a portal where i just need to enter my facebook credential and it will open the facebook content for me within my app screen.We cant manipulate anything from here.

### What i want a way to enter my facebook credentials and retrieve my all friends email addresses as list which i can use in my application as i want.like displaying them in a ListView

Like the yahoo.com which on asking facebook credentials , saves a csv file on to the desktop that has all the list of friends addresses. That means facebook do allow retrieval of friends email after proper authentication.

I tried FBRocket as well. it didnt seem to work...

How to programatically achieve this.

Comment: I think you'll need to use OAuth for this - don't think Facebook allows you to just enter your credentials anymore, to get access to an account (via the API).

Comment: is it not working on yahoo as well http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=058dc912c433f1b8&hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to acces the facebook graph api you'll need to use their SDK. You can download it from here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.  They provide you with a dialog box for the user to enter their user and password and obtain an oauth token.  Then using the Facebook object you can request anything on the graph path API.  As with the example they give you can use something similar to show the login dialog.

```
package com.greatap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Your friends list can be accessed using the graph path of /me/friends.

```
facebook.request("me/friends");
```

This should return something that looks like the following

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Fake",
         "id": "11111"
      },
      {
         "name": "Fake fakerson",
         "id": "111111"
      },
      {
         "name": "So Fake",
         "id": "111111111"
      }
    ]}
```

You can then access each user using their id and the open graph api to retrieve their email if it's visible to you.

```
fakebook.request("/111111111");
```

This will give you back a json array that contains your friends IDs.  You can then cycle through each of the friends and retrieve their information if it's available to you.

Comment: i am to able to get the Friends ID its a straight function available in the FBRocket SDK but the question is to retrieve the Friends Email Address.

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply but i am already done with the retrieval of Friends ID. Thw question was of retrieval of friends email address.  is there any api you know that on providing id returns email address ?.

Comment: I think fetching emails of friends is not possible. You must have permission for user using you app to get his email. Getting his friends email automatically is not allowed by facebook.

Comment: When do you the request for fakebook.request("/111111111"); it will give you back the info that is available to you.  If their email address is not visibile to you, you won't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not allow to access a email and phone no in any case.
The below link of facebook is already specify that Email is N/A [Not Applicable]

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 1):

Brain, even fakebook.request("/111111111") will give the info of friend with ID: "111111111" but it is always incomplete..
I have tried myself and found that in any condition Graph API is not giving out email and mobile no, (even if shared publicly) of friend.
Yes You can get your e-mail ID by `?field=email`
So, to get every friends contacts we need either all of their password and user name which is tedious or to get some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the end is Its not possible as Facebook dont permit to do so